# Show enum value in intellisense resharper

Tags: c#, resharper, intellisense

I`m looking for an option to show enum value in intellisense. Have a look at picture:

[image]

Is there any option in Resharper that lets me see the enum values in above intellisense box as they are listed in declaration?:

```
public enum FieldType
{
    Text = 1,
    MultiValueSelect = 2,
    TextArea = 4,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Visual Studio can display enum members **in alphabetical order only**. But Resharper overrides this behavior and offers you **"Sorting by relevance"** feature (by default).

Solution:

Set the `Environment -> IntelliSense -> Completion Behavior -> Sort items by` parameter to `Alphabetically` value in R# options.

Answer (score 0):

Default way to show an Enum value is alphabetically.

[image]

The image you are showing is overriding the default way. I think this is Resharper or "Productivity Power Tools" that show it that way.

Comment: Ok but how I can achieve same functionality in Resharper?