# show enum integer value in resharper intellisense

Tags: c#, enums, resharper, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

I did  some research but the closest answer to my question that I found was this:

[show-enum-value-in-intellisense-resharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607451/show-enum-value-in-intellisense-resharper) and it doesn't help me at all unfortunately.

Resharper is too lazy/abstinently to show the explicitly specified integer for an enum value in intellisense.

This is the original VS2022 intellisense behaviour:

[image]

And this is the resharper version:

[image]

Is it possible to get the original intellisense behaviour without disabling the entire resharper?

I'd be really happy about any hint.

Comment: the purpose of enums is to forget about magic numbers they represent (e.g. for me Sunday is definitely not 0 day of a week). if magic numbers matter, you can add them to summaries for enum fields

Answer (score 2):

You can't currently see enum values in ReSharper's IntelliSense popup. Please vote for [RSRP-464737](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-464737/Show-enum-values-in-intellisense-popup).

If you prefer, you can tell ReSharper to not override Visual Studio's IntelliSense on the "ReSharper | Options | Environment | IntelliSense | General" settings page.

Comment: nice, thank you for the link. Although it is a little discouraging to see that the request is 5 years old... :-( How do I vote up for it? do I need to log in?